# HTML Parsing - Convert a Text into a Link

Tags: php, javascript, html, parsing, dom

Supposed that I have this text:

> Aaron was implicated in the sin of his brother at Meribah (**Num. 20:8-13**), and on that account was not permitted to enter the Promised Land. When the tribes arrived at Mount Hor, "in the edge of the land of Edom," at the command of God Moses led Aaron and his son Eleazar to the top of that mountain, in the sight of all the people. There he stripped Aaron of his priestly vestments, and put them upon Eleazar; and there Aaron died on the top of the mount, being 123 years old (**Num. 20:23-29**. Comp. **Deut. 10:6**; **32:50**)

What I want to do is, **to convert every bold text above into a link**, and the link, if it is:

- Num. 20:8-12, should be like: < a href="num20.8-12">Num. 20:8-13< /a>
- Deut. 10:6; 32:50, should be like: < a href="deut10.6">Deut. 10:6< /a> < a href="deut32.50">Deut. 32:50< /a>

The structure of this text is like below:

```
<DIV>
  <B>Aaron</B>
  <SPAN>
    Aaron was implicated in the sin of his brother at Meribah (Num. 20:8-13), and on that account was not permitted to enter the Promised Land. When the tribes arrived at Mount Hor, "in the edge of the land of Edom," at the command of God Moses led Aaron and his son Eleazar to the top of that mountain, in the sight of all the people. There he stripped Aaron of his priestly vestments, and put them upon Eleazar; and there Aaron died on the top of the mount, being 123 years old (Num. 20:23-29. Comp. Deut. 10:6; 32:50)
  </SPAN>
</DIV>
```

Any great ideas would be appreciated. Thanks :)

---

**EDIT**

The code:

```
$chapters = array ("Deut", "Num");

$html = file_get_html($link);

foreach($html->find('div') as $dict) {
    $descr  = $dict->find('SPAN', 0)->innertext;    
    $descrl = preg_replace("/$chapters\. [0-9:-]*/", "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>", $descr); //--> See description below

    echo $descrl . "<hr/>";
}
```

Description: While I change the `$chapters` into a single word like `Num` or `Deut`, it works well, but while I change it into `$chapters`, it doesn't returns any link.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: try the regular expressions. Extract the strings needed, and replace it with what you want. For your first example ie. Num. 20:8-13, try /num\. [0-9:-]*/, which is precise enough in your context.

Comment: Are you okay to use javascript, as that is the way you modify the DOM of an HTML page?

Comment: @zoujyjs: Thanks, I will update the code soon..

Comment: @Markasoftware: Yes, of course..

Comment: What language are you trying to implement this in? You added the [tag:JavaScript] tag, but the code you posted is [tag:PHP] although you have not tagged it as PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify the rules, which you should define and improve for yourself; I've handled your specific case.

```
//replace against either book followed by period followed by space
//followed by one or more digit, comma, semicolon, space, or dash
txt.replace(/(Num|Deut)\. ([\d:,; -]+)/g, function (match, book, verses) {
    var link = '';
    //split the verse on semicolon + space as each must be linked
    verses.split(/;\s+/).forEach(function (elem) {
        //create the link; replace : with period
        link += '<a href="' + book.toLowerCase() + elem.replace(':', '.') + '">'
            + book + '. ' + elem + '</a> ';
    });
    return link;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XaVXW/